# unordered_map: which key does emplace(x.y, move(x)) use?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have code looking roughly like this:

```
struct Foo {
    std::string str;
    //...
};

void foo(Foo&& val)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo> m;
    m.emplace(val.str, move(val));
}
```

Does the `emplace` call insert the the value of `val` at the key having the original value of `val.str`, or can it happen that the (unspecified) moved-from value of `val.str` is used as key?

Since `unordered_map`'s `value_type` is a `std::pair`, I think it boils down to the question in which order the members of `std::pair` can be arranged. Is there a guarantee that `.first` occurs before `.second` or are implementations allowed to allocate `.second` before `.first`?

Comment: In general the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified (or undefined pre-C++17) so my first thought is that your code is potentially dangerous.  I don't know if the rules change at all when forwarding arguments to a constructor.

Comment: The argument evaluation order is irrelevant, because arguments are forwarded by reference: the key by lvalue reference, and the value by rvalue reference. The references are dereferenced only when the `value_type` is initialized. That is the whole point of `emplace`.

Comment: I *think* that `pair::pair` must initialise `first` before `second`, because member initialises operate in member declaration order, `first` precedes `second` in the declaration and `pair` in general can contain non-default constructable values. see [pairs.pair](http://eel.is/c++draft/pairs.pair)

Comment: @Caleth Thanks. Since the declaration is clearly specified in the Standard, implementations have no choice. The initialization order is well-defined, and my code is safe.

Comment: @j6t correct but what happens if the implementation moves the `val` before copying `str`, there are no requirement, AFAIK that says they'd need to do that in order. It can potentially be dangerous. I'd say it will probably fine 99% of the time but it is not a good practice.

Comment: @AR5HAM good point. However, the [unordered container requirements](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:HashRequirements) specify that `emplace` must construct `value_type` using `std​::​forward<​Args​>(​args)...`. This means that the arguments are forwarded by reference and early movement is not allowed.