# std::map::try_emplace return value results in a dangling pointer when retrieving a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++20, stdmap

I have a factory function that returns a non-owning pointer to the created object *after it is inserted into a resource-owning map* to be later stored as a non-owning pointer elsewhere; however, by using the return value of `std::map::try_emplace` which should be an iterator to what was/is inserted, this causes the internal contents of the `std::unique_ptr` to be invalid when accessed through the referring non-owning pointer.

Instead, I have to call `std::map::find` and basically search for a value twice.

I don't quite understand what's wrong with the non-working version of the code below.

Shouldn't the return value of `std::map::try_emplace` be directly usable/copyable?

What I wanted to do, but doesn't work:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Feature>> Feature::s_registry{};

Feature* Feature::CreateFeature(Map* map, const XMLElement& elem) {
    auto new_feature = std::make_unique<Feature>(map, elem);
    //Copy name out so it isn't erased via the move operation.
    std::string new_feature_name = new_feature->name;
    if(auto&& [where, inserted] = s_registry.try_emplace(new_feature_name, std::move(new_feature)); inserted) {
        return where->second.get();
    } else {
        if(where != std::end(s_registry)) {
            return where->second.get();
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Instead I have to call `find` to get a valid iterator:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Feature>> Feature::s_registry{};

Feature* Feature::CreateFeature(Map* map, const XMLElement& elem) {
    auto new_feature = std::make_unique<Feature>(map, elem);
    //Copy name out so it isn't erased via the move operation.
    std::string new_feature_name = new_feature->name;
    if(const auto where_inserted = s_registry.try_emplace(new_feature_name, std::move(new_feature)); where_inserted.second) {
        if(const auto found = s_registry.find(new_feature_name); found != std::end(s_registry)) {
            return found->second.get();
        }
    } else {
        if(const auto found = s_registry.find(new_feature_name); found != std::end(s_registry)) {
            return found->second.get();
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: `but doesn't work:` is not a description of a problem. What does it mean or better provide [mcve].

Comment: @MarekR Taken blindly at face value the phrase "doesn't work" is not descriptive. **That's what the entire preceding paragraph was for**. Try reading harder instead of skimming looking for keywords to latch on to.

Comment: It's really unclear whether you're saying that `where->second.get()` is invalid at that point, that the `Feature*` returned is incorrect, or that the `unique_ptr` stored in the map gets corrupted. Try clarifying your text _or showing self-explanatory code_ instead of snapping at people offering help.

Comment: FWIW it looks as if the `auto&&` structured binding might be declaring rvalue references to the prvalue which disappears at the end of the full expression. I can't tell if that's a plausible explanation though, as your problem description is so unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code can be as simple as

```
Feature* Feature::CreateFeature(Map* map, const XMLElement& elem)
{
    auto new_feature = std::make_unique<Feature>(map, elem);
    return s_registry.emplace(new_feature->name, std::move(new_feature)).first->second.get();
}
```

If the `new_feature` was not inserted because the slot is already occupied, `.first` points to the already existing value. Otherwise, it points to the newly inserted object. In both cases, that object's `->second` should be valid.

Furthermore, `std::move` does not move anything. The members that `new_feature` points to can be used until the final destination is initialized, at which point the `std::map` will already know where to insert the value. Therefore, it is not necessary to keep `new_feature->name` in a separate value. There is some discussion of this behavior in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800156/unordered-map-which-key-does-emplacex-y-movex-use).